# c# Telegarm bot вывести сообщение посреди экрана

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Как вывести сообщение в телеграмм боте посредине экрана, пример на скриншоте

[image: C]

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    public async Task Notification(string message, string url = null!)
    {
        if(update.CallbackQuery != null)
        await client.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(update.CallbackQuery.Id, message, showAlert: true, url: url);
    }
```